# bash prompt and echoing colors inside a function

Tags: bash, function, colors, echo

I have this in my .bashrc:

```
LIGHTGREEN="\[\033[1;32m\]"
LIGHTRED="\[\033[1;31m\]"
WHITE="\[\033[0;37m\]"
RESET="\[\033[0;00m\]"

function error_test {
    if [[ $? = "0" ]]; then
        echo -e "$LIGHTGREEN"
    else
        echo -e "$LIGHTRED"
    fi
}

PS1="\u\$(error_test)@\w$RESET \$ "
```

This seems to make the shell output exactly:

`username\[\]@~/`

The escaping [ and ] around the color codes are showing up in my prompt. If I remove the escape codes from around the colors it works, but then bash line wrapping fails stupendously.

Note if do `PS1="LIGHTGREEN - whatever - $RESET"` it works and the [ and ] are not escaped. However, I want to do this inside a function, which seems to be the issue.

I can't find any good documentation on this. `man echo` doesn't even list a -e option. Bash seems like it has a lot of undocumented, handmedown knowledge.

Comment: `help echo` lists several bash-specific options.

Comment: And the reason this is so is that the manual pages are for the external variant.  You have `/bin/echo` which is documented in `man 1 echo`, and you have Bash's builtin function `echo` which is documented in `help echo`.  See `help help` and `man bash` for more on this.

Comment: Welcome to 2017! For future travelers, the simplest answer is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43462720/746890. (i.e. Just swap `\[` for `\001` and `\[` for `\002`.)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I found this topic looking for answer how to set bash color with escaping `\[ \]` from bash function.

Actually there is solution. Bash allows to generate `PS1` prompt each time prompt is rendered.

```
set_bash_prompt(){
    PS1="\u@\h $(call_your_function) $>"
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=set_bash_prompt
```

This way, PS1 will be interpreted each time prompt will be displayed, so it will call function and render properly all escaping sequences including `\[ \]`  which are important for counting length of prompt (e.g. to make command history work correctly).

Hopefully this will help someone, as I spend half a day to solve this issue.

Comment: This is the solution. See @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams earlier answer for why it works.

Comment: Why do you prefer using `PROMPT_COMMAND` to putting the function call in `PS1`?

Comment: @l0b0 The usage of `PROMPT_COMMAND` is needed if you play with colors in the `call_your_function`.  Otherwise, length of prompt is not counting right and command history wraps badly.

Comment: @Tonin No, you can use colours properly in `PS1` commands. [Example](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/54ee46d965eb0ec4700439dd55cdf5bf387239b8/.bashrc#L60)

Comment: @l0b0 The example you are giving breaks history line wrapping (using ^-r) when the previous command returns an error (ie: when your `printf` is triggered).

Comment: @Tonin Ah, I think I see. When I run `false`, then press Ctrl-r, search for "false", and then press Enter, the command line is shown as `$ false false`, even though only `false` was run. Is that what you mean? And if that's the case, does that mean the length of `PS1` is *not* counted when searching, but at some earlier time?

Comment: @Tonin Looks like [neither solution works](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105926/how-to-include-commands-in-bashs-ps1-without-breaking-line-length-calculation).

Comment: This works great, thanks! Unfortunately, it breaks Terminal.app's ability to open new tabs rooted to the active tab's path. This ability can be restored like so: `PROMPT_COMMAND="set_bash_prompt; $PROMPT_COMMAND"` See http://superuser.com/a/623305/75328 for more details.

Comment: This works great!  Helped fix a issue I had trying to insert a newline after each command output, which was breaking the prompt if I had a long path.  Just added an extra 'echo' at the end of the function and now it's working like it should!  Thanks!

Answer (score 43):

Use `\001` instead of `\[` and `\002` instead of `\]`, and be aware of the consequences of using`PROMPT_COMMAND` as that method will reset the prompt every single time (which can also be just what you want).

The solution for bash prompt echoing colors inside a function is explained [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/053):

> The `\[` `\]` are only special when you assign PS1, if you print them
>   inside a function that runs when the prompt is displayed it doesn't
>   work. In this case you need to use the bytes `\001` and `\002`

There is also [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/301355) that points in the same direction:

> bash-specific `\[` and `\]` are in fact translated to `\001` and `\002`

Setting `PS1` inside a function called by `PROMPT_COMMAND` as suggested in the accepted aswer resets `PS1` every single time not allowing other scripts to easily modify your promtp (for example Python virtualnenv [activate.sh](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/master/virtualenv_embedded/activate.sh)):

```
$ echo $PS1
<your PS1>
$ PS1="(TEST)$PS1"
$ echo $PS1
<(TEST) is not prepended to PS1 if you are using PROMPT_COMMAND as it is reset>
```

Comment: Holy cow – I can't believe this question is 6 years old, and by some luck, you posted the only working solution three days ago! Thanks so much. This needs more upvotes :)

Comment: This solution worked to me in conjunction with using `printf` instead of `echo`.

Comment: Oh my goodness, you're a hero. This worked perfectly and immediately, while also helping me actually understand what was going wrong. Thank you so much.

Comment: A good question would be - why does everyone( PS1 tutorials) say to escape colors with `\[` instead of teaching more versatile `\001` right away. Edit: I was wrong, ofc Arch Linux tutorial mentions it right away! :D

Comment: Glad I found this and got this working using `printf "%b"` and `echo -e` inside a function. Thanks !

Answer (score 8):

`\[` and `\]` must be used in `$PS*` directly, rather than just having them output via `echo`.

```
LIGHTGREEN="\033[1;32m"
LIGHTRED="\033[1;31m"
WHITE="\033[0;37m"
RESET="\033[0;00m"

function error_test {
    if [[ $? = "0" ]]; then
        echo -e "$LIGHTGREEN"
    else
        echo -e "$LIGHTRED"
    fi
}

PS1="\u\[\$(error_test)\]@\w\[$RESET\] \$ "
```

Comment: What about the case where a function echoes more than a color? What if it outputs `echo -e "$LIGHTGREEN some stuff $RESET"` ? This solution - wrapping the function call in `\[` and `\]` - seems to have the same problem

Comment: That's why you can't do it that way.

Comment: You're saying that it's impossible in bash to have a function that echoes colors and text? 

Comment: There must be another way - I have some fairly complicated logic that I want to use to build my bash prompt, too lengthy to put all into one PS1= line, so I put it in a function. I don't even know if it could realistically be put into one line. I would like to colorize the output with multiple colors.

Comment: My own [.bashrc](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/.bashrc) does use functions and multiple colors in `$PS1`. It Just Works (TM).

Comment: Of course there is a way: `echo -e "\001${red}\002"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the coloured exit code portion of [my `PS1` code](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/cb1df10bddb4dafecac0e0641195549b477f583a/.bashrc#L52-L64):

```
color_enabled() {
    local -i colors=$(tput colors 2>/dev/null)
    [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && [[ $colors -gt 2 ]]
}

BOLD_FORMAT="${BOLD_FORMAT-$(color_enabled && tput bold)}"
ERROR_FORMAT="${ERROR_FORMAT-$(color_enabled && tput setaf 1)}"
RESET_FORMAT="${RESET_FORMAT-$(color_enabled && tput sgr0)}"

# Exit code
PS1='$(exit_code=$?; [[ $exit_code -eq 0 ]] || printf %s $BOLD_FORMAT $ERROR_FORMAT $exit_code $RESET_FORMAT " ")'
```

Screenshot (with one Subversion repository path anonymized):
[image: Color coded output]

Comment: Grargh, stupid Stackoverflow comments. Let's try this again: I tried your method and it seems to have the same problem mine does, which is that bash line wrapping breaks. Typing past the end of a line makes the text wrap onto the same line. Am I doing something wrong? : https://gist.github.com/1071081

Comment: To clarify you're edit: your solution is now to put the entire contents of the function in a string, and make the prompt execute that string, yes?

Comment: also, if I try to make exit code a function in a string, and do $(${exit_code}), the code stays the same. is that because other commands like tput are resetting it?

Comment: Re. your first comment: Yes, try to remove the last line and `echo "$ps1_command"`. You must pack functionality in a string if you want it to be run on each display of the prompt, instead of only once at login.

Comment: Re. your second comment: I don't understand. What *exactly* are you doing?

Comment: Thanks! This answer was a brilliant starter to writing my own prompt customizations!

Comment: @AndyRay: [I don't use that anymore](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/.bashrc), but it was to make sure that I don't get any `Undefined variable` errors - `${ps1_command:-}` means "if the variable `ps1_command` is empty or undefined, substitute the empty string, otherwise substitute the value of `ps1_command`".

Comment: @AndyRay The line wrapping and command history issue doesn't seem to be solved with this answer nor with your Bash Prompt Builder.  The answer from @ thedk was the only one working for me.

Comment: @Tonin Can you demonstrate how it's not solved? I'd love to know about it if I have bugs in my `.bashrc`.

Comment: @l0b0 Using your piece of code in my .bashrc, when I do `ctrl-r` to go back into history, with an exit code > 0, the prompt gets eaten on the right (ie: character count is not correct).

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old topic, but I just got this working with functions.  The trick is to split the printing and non-printing parts of the function up so you can correctly bracket the non-printing parts with [ ].  Normally I like my ERROR.. line to be separate (and this isn't a problem then), but this also works correctly if everything is all in one line.

Note that I return the previous $? value from each sub-shell so $? gets propagated from one to the next.

```
PS1="\n\
\[\`
  cja_prv_retval=\$?;
  if [ \$cja_prv_retval != 0 ];
     then echo -ne \$E_ERROR;
  fi
  exit \$cja_prv_retval
\`\]\
\`
  cja_prv_retval=\$?;
  if [ \$cja_prv_retval != 0 ];
     then echo -ne \"ERROR: RETURN CODE \$cja_prv_retval\";
  fi
  exit \$cja_prv_retval
\`\
\[\`
  cja_prv_retval=\$?;
  if [ \$cja_prv_retval != 0 ];
     then echo -ne \$E_RESET;
  fi
  exit \$cja_prv_retval
\`\]\
${P_RESET}${P_GRAY}\! \t ${P_RED}\u${P_GRAY}@${P_GREEN}\h ${P_YELLOW}\w ${P_CYAN}   ══>${P_RESET} "
```

This gives me either

```
2021 12:28:05 cja@morpheus04 ~ ══>
```

if there is no error, or

```
ERROR: RETURN CODE 1 2021 12:28:16 cja@morpheus04 ~ ══>
```

if there is an error.  Everything is correctly spaced (multi-line history editing works correctly).

Comment: You can also see how I did it in my complete function http://andrewray.me/bash-prompt-builder/index.html

Comment: The return code chaining trick helped me solve a puzzle with my prompt; previously, I could either safely bracket color codes for sane editing, or have a function generate different prompts based on the last exit code, but not both due to the subshell making passing variables impossible.

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine.

```
LIGHTGREEN="\e[32m"
LIGHTRED="\e[31m"
RESET="\e[0m"

error_test () {
    if [[ $? = "0" ]]; then
        echo -e "$LIGHTGREEN"
    else
        echo -e "$LIGHTRED"
    fi
}
export PS1=$(printf "$(error_test) $(whoami)@${RESET}$(pwd) ")
```